# How can I put python files on a raspberry pi pico without using software like thonny

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Is there a way for me to put python files (micropython to be specific) on the raspberry pi pico without using software like thonny where it does it for you, Is there a way to do it with bootsel?

Comment: rshell: [link](https://www.mfitzp.com/using-micropython-raspberry-pico/)  or mpremote [link] (https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/reference/mpremote.html) may help.

Answer (score 0):

With bootsel button you will not reach the storage for python scripts.

Using rshell will help. Inside rshell you will also reach REPL.